# Close android app programatically, on callback to URL intent

Tags: android, intentfilter, url-scheme

In case my app is opened using URL intent (Intent Filter using URL schemes) , I want to quit my app before returning to the calling app.

Comment: Define what you mean by "quit my app".  Android controls the lifetime of your app process.  If you have an activity that you want to stop showing, simply call finish() inside it.

Comment: I mean, it should not be in the background, when I go back to the calling app. When the user quits the calling app, he should no land on my app.

Comment: The Android platform controls the lifetime of the *process* hosting your app. It's an error to assume that you have control - it simply does not work like desktop software. But you can control what your app *displays* on screen.

Answer (score 0):

This line will do it:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: There's never a reason to do this.

Comment: We have a kiosk app and we need a way for techs to exit the app.  We've overridden the home button.

Comment: Any reason why you could not finish every activity?  That's effectively the same thing for the purpose of UI.

Comment: I am aware of this, but we are often advised against using this line.